# Number of words which are created from 19 letters

Tags: permutations

There is a set of 19 characters A,B,C,. . . ,S. What is the maximum number of words of 16 characters that can be created from them if we require them to contain the character A is present once, character B is present twice, character C is present three times, and the other characters at most once? (regardless of whether they make sense).

My idea is to do permutations of a multiset: $\frac{16!}{1!*2!*3!}$ and the result is $120$. Is it right?

Comment: You do not seem to have taking account of the choices of the other letters to include

Comment: Can you please help me how them taking into account please? I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

Choose the $10$ characters from the remaining $16$ ones and then permute (each choice is the same multiset "type" (i.e. the amounts are same):

$$
\binom{16}{10} \frac{16!}{3! \cdot 2! \cdot (1!)^{11}} = 13962475118592000.
$$

Comment: But we choose 10 characters from remaining 16, or not?

Comment: @baranovak Oh yes, I got the numbers mixed up.

Comment: And is it really right? I also tried this calculation:
${16 \choose 1}\cdot  {15 \choose 2}\cdot  {13 \choose 3}\cdot \frac{16!}{(16-10)!}$

Comment: Yes, that gives the same answer! So in your way you're like choosing the places for C, B and A and then the rest is a 10-permutation from 16 (i.e. choosing the remaining with order mattering and then putting them in that order to the free places not used by A's, B's and C's.

Comment: Yes, that´s true! thank you so much!